# Is my sentence meaningful?

Tags: writing

> The moon is a very romantic place for people.

Is my sentence meaningful? In an article, I've read a sentence:

> The moon has been described by songwriters and poets as a place for a romantic escape.

According to the sentence, is my sentence acceptable?

Comment: Your sentence is a good, short, "meaningful" paraphrase of the longer sentence.

Answer (score 5):

Your sentence is acceptable in some science fiction scenario, where people can easily visit the Moon and it is considered to be quite romantic here. Songs and poetry may allow this as well, though I think the Moon would be a tool of creating romantic atmosphere, not a romantic place.

Comment: I agree with you that the moon is known for creating a romantic atmosphere more than it is known for being a romantic place. However, there is the famous song from the 1950s: "Fly me to the Moon."